# How to receive data from multiple clients with Python Socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to make a 2 player online LAN game that. I have created the server and the clients, they can connect. The problem is that when 2 clients try to send information, the server doesn't handle the info from both clients correctly but it handles it correctly when only one client is connected.
This is the server code:

```
import socket
import os

numOfClients = 0
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

serversocket.bind(('192.168.88.1', 10000))
serversocket.listen(5)
while numOfClients != 2:
    if numOfClients == 0:
        c, a = serversocket.accept()
    elif numOfClients == 1:
        c1, a1 = serversocket.accept()
    if numOfClients == 0:
        print(a, 'has connected!')
    elif numOfClients == 1:
        print(a1, 'has connected!')
    numOfClients += 1
    print('Connected to ', a)
print("2 Players have connected!")
while True:
    msg1 = c.recv(1024)
    if msg1 != b'':
        print(msg1, '1')
    msg2 = c1.recv(1024)
    if msg2 != b'':
        print(msg2, '2')
```

This is all the client code that you really need:

```
# Socket Stuff
port = 10000
host = '192.168.88.1'
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server = host, port
socket.connect(server)
socketMsg = b''

# Main Game loop
while True:
    # Calls Functions
    socket.send(socketMsg)
    # socketMsg is assigned above, it is assigned to b'Works!' just so that I can see if it actually works
    socketMsg = b''
    redrawWin()
    get_events()
```

If I did anything wrong in this post, I am sorry, this is my second post on stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first socket connection blocked later connection. There are multiple solutions for this.

- Use nonblocking mode. `select` module is designed to manage this.
- Use multithreading which means each client will have a independent thread.
- Use [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

Comment: Thank you, I have already found a solution for this, but I will try your solutions to improve my game, thank you!